# Can't install PHP Package on CentOS

Tags: php, linux, centos, yum

I am having trouble re-installing PHP via yum on my server hosted by digital ocean.

I had PHP 5.4 installed but wanted 5.6. I added/enabled the remi repo's, ran `yum -y remove php*` and then tried to re-install php.

When I run `yum -y install php` I get the following:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.centos.webair.com
 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: mirrors.centos.webair.com
 * remi: remi.check-update.co.uk
 * remi-php56: remi.check-update.co.uk
 * updates: mirrors.centos.webair.com
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.8-1.el6.remi for package: php-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.8-1.el6.remi for package: php-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-zip(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.7-1.el6.remi.5.6 will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-zip.x86_64 0:1.12.5-1.el6.remi.5.6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
           Installed: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.x86_64 (@base)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.mojowill.com/geek/howto-install-php-5-4-5-5-or-5-6-on-centos-6-and-centos-7/)

I'm a bit stuck. I have tried removing httpd, re-installing httpd, nothing seems to fix this. I even get the error when I disable remi and try and install PHP 5.4.

Any ideas on where to go from here?

I am running CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

Comment: If you have **DirectAdmin** installed, have a look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84212/123630

Comment: I ran into this issue because I thought I was on Cent 6.8 but it was Cent 7.5. So I had to do a yum clean all and configured with the correct 7.5 repo url.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I fixed it! The issue was that I had the wrong version of EL installed.
I removed all my extra repo's, removed all php packages, removed httpd.
Ran the following:

```
yum install epel-release
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
yum clean
yum update
```

I was then able to install PHP using the following

```
yum install php56w php56w-opcache php56w-mcrypt php56w-pdo php56w-mysql
```

Comment: `sudo yum clean all` seems to have been the key in my case

Comment: No package php56w available.
No package php56w-opcache available.
No package php56w-mcrypt available.
No package php56w-pdo available.
No package php56w-mysql available.
Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered the same problem while installing php70w(webstatic) on my linux machine. The following command helped me to install php70

```
sudo yum clean all   // to clear all caches
```

after clearing cache again install php70 using:

```
sudo yum install php70
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this probably suits serverfault or poweruser better, I will still answer.

This is based from experience and works every single time if done as instructed.

> To install, first you must add the Webtatic EL yum repository
>   information corresponding to your CentOS/RHEL version to yum:
>
> CentOS/RHEL 7.x:
>
> ```
> rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/epel-release.rpm
> rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
> ```

Then you can install each of your individual packages like this:

```
yum install php56w-<package name>
```

Don't forget the php56w prefix though.

Source: https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/

---

Try this (in regards to the comments):

```
yum update -y; yum remove httpd && yum install httpd; yum install php56w-common php56w-opcache php56w-mysql
```

Comment: I was just doing it :) I'm afraid not. I now get the following: http://pastebin.com/M2tAjH6K

Comment: I just ran yum install php56w-common manually and it installed ok, but now I'm getting the same old "Required: httpd-mmn = 20051115"

Comment: I'll add more to the post just to check if it works.

Comment: Oops, let me edit the post. Check the PHP commands again, I was typing 55 all along. :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77450/discussion-between-sysvoid-and-novalty).