# Installing PHP5.6 on RHEL

Tags: php, php-5.6, rhel7

I am trying to install PHP 5.6 on RHEL 7 (physical machine) using yum. I installed the REMI repositories.

```
[root@localhost Sridhar_P]# yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.
repo id                                        repo name                                                                               status
*epel/x86_64                                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                          enabled: 10,416
epel-debuginfo/x86_64                          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Debug                                  disabled
epel-source/x86_64                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Source                                 disabled
epel-testing/x86_64                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64                                disabled
epel-testing-debuginfo/x86_64                  Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64 - Debug                        disabled
epel-testing-source/x86_64                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64 - Source                       disabled
mysql-connectors-community/x86_64              MySQL Connectors Community                                                              enabled:     21
mysql-connectors-community-source              MySQL Connectors Community - Source                                                     disabled
mysql-tools-community/x86_64                   MySQL Tools Community                                                                   enabled:     36
mysql-tools-community-source                   MySQL Tools Community - Source                                                          disabled
mysql55-community/x86_64                       MySQL 5.5 Community Server                                                              disabled
mysql55-community-source                       MySQL 5.5 Community Server - Source                                                     disabled
mysql56-community/x86_64                       MySQL 5.6 Community Server                                                              enabled:    259
mysql56-community-source                       MySQL 5.6 Community Server - Source                                                     disabled
mysql57-community-dmr/x86_64                   MySQL 5.7 Community Server Development Milestone Release                                disabled
mysql57-community-dmr-source                   MySQL 5.7 Community Server Development Milestone Release - Source                       disabled
nginx/x86_64                                   nginx repo                                                                              enabled:     28
remi                                           Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                   enabled:  3,287
remi-debuginfo/x86_64                          Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                       enabled:  1,244
remi-php55                                     Remi's PHP 5.5 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                           disabled
remi-php55-debuginfo/x86_64                    Remi's PHP 5.5 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo               disabled
remi-php56                                     Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                           enabled:    361
remi-php56-debuginfo/x86_64                    Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo               enabled:    246
remi-safe                                      Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                              disabled
remi-test                                      Remi's test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                              enabled:    636
remi-test-debuginfo/x86_64                     Remi's test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                  enabled:    198
webtatic/x86_64                                Webtatic Repository EL7 - x86_64                                                        disabled
webtatic-archive/x86_64                        Webtatic Repository EL7 - x86_64 - Archive                                              disabled
webtatic-archive-debuginfo/x86_64              Webtatic Repository EL7 - x86_64 - Archive Debug                                        disabled
webtatic-archive-source                        Webtatic Repository EL7 - x86_64 - Archive Source                                       disabled
webtatic-debuginfo/x86_64                      Webtatic Repository EL7 - x86_64 - Debug                                                disabled
webtatic-source                                Webtatic Repository EL7 - x86_64 - Source                                               disabled
webtatic-testing/x86_64                        Webtatic Repository EL7 - x86_64 - Testing                                              disabled
webtatic-testing-debuginfo/x86_64              Webtatic Repository EL7 - x86_64 - Testing Debug                                        disabled
webtatic-testing-source                        Webtatic Repository EL7 - x86_64 - Testing Source                                       disabled
```

I then ran

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

and then tried installing php by running

```
yum install php php-fpm php-mcrypt php-imap php-gd php-mbstring php-mysql php-dom
```

I got the following error

```
[root@localhost Sridhar_P]# yum install php php-fpm php-mcrypt php-imap php-gd php-mbstring php-mysql php-dom
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.
Package php-mysql is obsoleted by php-mysqlnd, trying to install php-mysqlnd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 instead
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664 for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-fpm.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc-client.so.2007()(64bit) for package: php-imap-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi for package: php-mysqlnd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gd-last.x86_64 0:2.2.3-1.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package libc-client.x86_64 0:2007f-4.el7.1 will be installed
---> Package libmcrypt.x86_64 0:2.5.8-13.el7 will be installed
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664 for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-zip(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664 for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.10-1.el7.remi.5.6 will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-zip.x86_64 0:1.13.4-1.el7.remi.5.6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-pecl-zip-1.13.4-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libzip-last.x86_64 0:1.1.3-1.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664 for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
       Requires: httpd
Error: Package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
       Requires: libt1.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
       Requires: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Found a solution  [at this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154245/cant-install-php-package-on-centos) which recommends that the Webtatic EL be installed. I installed webtatic did a yum update and ran

```
yum install php56w php56w-fpm php56w-mcrypt php56w-gd php56w-imap php56w-mbstring php56w-mysql php56w-dom
```

I get dependency errors

```
[root@localhost Sridhar_P]# yum install php56w php56w-fpm php56w-mcrypt php56w-gd php56w-imap php56w-mbstring php56w-mysql php56w-dom
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
remi-safe                                                                                                                      | 2.9 kB      00:00:00     
Package php56w is obsoleted by php, trying to install php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 instead
Package php56w-fpm is obsoleted by php-fpm, trying to install php-fpm-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 instead
Package php56w-mcrypt is obsoleted by php-mcrypt, trying to install php-mcrypt-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 instead
Package php56w-gd is obsoleted by php-gd, trying to install php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 instead
Package php56w-imap is obsoleted by php-imap, trying to install php-imap-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 instead
Package php56w-mbstring is obsoleted by php-mbstring, trying to install php-mbstring-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 instead
Package php56w-mysql is obsoleted by php-mysqlnd, trying to install php-mysqlnd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 instead
Package php56w-xml is obsoleted by php-xml, trying to install php-xml-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 instead
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664 for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-fpm.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc-client.so.2007()(64bit) for package: php-imap-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi for package: php-mysqlnd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gd-last.x86_64 0:2.2.3-1.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package libc-client.x86_64 0:2007f-4.el7.1 will be installed
---> Package libmcrypt.x86_64 0:2.5.8-13.el7 will be installed
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664 for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed    
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-zip(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664 for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.10-1.el7.remi.5.6 will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-zip.x86_64 0:1.13.4-1.el7.remi.5.6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-pecl-zip-1.13.4-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libzip-last.x86_64 0:1.1.3-1.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664 for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
       Requires: httpd
Error: Package: php-gd-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
       Requires: libt1.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.6.25-0.1.RC1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
       Requires: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am wondering if I am missing something? it seems I am going around in circles! I install one complete stack on a Centos machine every week but getting past this in RHEl seems to be a challenge. Any pointers on what I should be looking for? (BTW I can't find the remi-test repo mentioned at the bottom of the message)

Comment: do you really need deprecated and not supported php-mysql?

Comment: You should use latest php7!

Comment: 1st: too much repo can only raise issue.

Comment: @Jits - there are good reasons for not using php7 for now; there are a number of applications that have not been upgraded to support it yet... if OP wants to use one of those apps then he need 5.6. Going forward, everyone should be thinking of migrating to php7, but right now we need to be pragmatic about it.

Comment: @RemiCollet. Thank you. Trying a fresh install

Comment: @Jits We use Drupal 7 (we have rolled out custom modules) and Drupal recommends that we use PHP 5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is
>   not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign
>   subscriptions.

This is an issue without official repositories, you won't find some dependencies.

> ```
>   Requires: libt1.so.5()(64bit)
> ```

t1lib is part of base repository, so... you really need to register this system.

> ```
>   Requires: httpd
> ```

Same issue.

BTW why do you enable so much repositories, if you want PHP 5.6, you only need "remi-safe" and "remi-php56" (not remi, remi-test, and not webtatic which can only create conflicts).

Comment: Trying a fresh install.

Comment: Installed PHP5.6. Issue was with multiple repositories.