# Trying to update PHP from 5.4 to 5.6 on CentOS 7 - Getting an error (and website down now)

Tags: php, apache, centos

I was trying to update my PHP, but when I used yum update php, this is what I got:

```
Error: Package: gd-last-2.2.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libwebp.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
           Removing: php-pdo-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7
           Updated By: php-pdo-5.6.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.30-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-pdo-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
           Available: php-pdo-5.6.29-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.29-1.el6.remi
Error: Package: php-5.6.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
           Installed: httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.4.x86_64 (@updates)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
           Available: httpd-2.4.6-45.el7.centos.x86_64 (base)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
           Available: httpd-2.4.6-45.el7.centos.4.x86_64 (updates)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried using --skip-broken, then rebooted, but my version it didnt help. I searched this site and came across a thread which I followed ([Can't install PHP Package on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154245/cant-install-php-package-on-centos/)).

Basically this is what I typed first:

```
yum install epel-release
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
yum clean
yum update
```

got exactly the same error as before (so I guess it did nothing). Then I did this:

```
yum update -y; yum remove httpd && yum install httpd; yum install php56w-common php56w-opcache php56w-mysql
```

This is the error I got (so I though part of the problem has been resolved):

```
Error: Package: gd-last-2.2.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libwebp.so.5()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

But just in case, I visited my website, and now am getting a 502 error :( :( - I cant even connect to Sentora (which I had installed). When I try to reinstall sentora (so that maybe it'll fix it), it says it needs a clean server as mariadb is already installed!! **Please help me!!**

regards

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Package: php-5.6.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>              Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
>              Installed: httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.4.x86_64 (@updates)

You have obviously a bad configuration, mixing repository for CentOS 6 on a CentOS 7 server.

So, remove the badly installed packages:

```
yum remove remi-release epel-release webtatic-release
yum clean all
```

Then, see the [configuration wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) and install the correct configuration packages for remi and epel repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the /etc/yum.conf file and see if httpd and/or httpd* packages are excluded from update. If so, modify the yum.conf exclude line and remove httpd* packages, run 'yum clean all', then try to update PHP again.

Answer (score 0):

You updated your `epel`, but did not clean.

You can use bellow commands for install your php5.6:

```
yum clean all
yum install php56w
```